# How to assign a value returned from a function to a variable in GDB script?

Tags: debugging, gdb

For example, consider the following debugging session:

```
(gdb) break foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004f1: file tst.c, line 5.

(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/tst 
Breakpoint 1, foo () at tst.c:5
5         return ary[i++];

(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  foo () at tst.c:5
Value returned is $1 = 1

(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Breakpoint 1, foo () at tst.c:5
5         return ary[i++];

(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  foo () at tst.c:5
Value returned is $2 = 3
```

After executing a `finish` command, I get the return value assigned to a
convenience variable (e.g. `$1` or `$2`). Unfortunately, every time the command
is executed, the value is assigned to a different variable. That's the problem,
I cannot write a script which examines the returned value cause I don't know
what variable the value was assigned to.

Why do I need that? I want to set a breakpoint at a certain function but to
stop program execution only if the function has returned a specific value. Something
like this:

```
break foo
commands
  finish
  if ($return_value != 42)
    continue;
  end
end
```

So the question is: Is there any way to examine in a script the value returned
from a function?

Comment: You can use `$` to access the most recent value in gdb's [value history](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Value-History.html). I don't know whether you can have commands in a breakpoint command list that will actually run after a `finish` command, though.

Comment: Wow! I tried a dozen of various combinations like $$ or $? but it turned out to be much simpler. However, it seems that indeed no more commands are executed after a `finish` command. Anyway, if you convert your comment into an answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your question is straightforward: just use `$` to access the most recent value in gdb's value history.

From [GDB: Value History](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Value-History.html)

> The values printed are given history numbers by which you can refer to them. These are successive integers starting with one. print shows you the history number assigned to a value by printing ‘$num = ’ before the value; here num is the history number.
>
> To refer to any previous value, use ‘$’ followed by the value's history number. The way print labels its output is designed to remind you of this. **Just $ refers to the most recent value in the history**, and $$ refers to the value before that. $$n refers to the nth value from the end.

But, executing commands following a `finish` command in a breakpoint command list may not currently be possible; see [Tom Tromey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33808923/2554472) for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't easy to do from the gdb CLI.  Maybe it is impossible purely using the traditional CLI -- because you can have inferior control commands like `finish` in a breakpoint's commands.  This is a longstanding gdb issue.

However, like most automation problems in gdb, it can be solved using the Python API.  Now, unfortunately, this approach requires a bit of work on your part.

Essentially what you want to do is subclass the Python [FinishBreakpoint class](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Finish-Breakpoints-in-Python.html) to have it do what you want.  In particular you want to write a new command that will set a regular breakpoint in some function; then when this breakpoint is hit, it will instantiate your new `FinishBreakpoint` class.  Your class will have a `stop` method that will use the `return_value` of the finish breakpoint as you like.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is possible with python. But I was curious if it was possible in interactive mode from command line interface.